# How to load a module with Ajax Joomla

Tags: ajax, joomla

I am working on a joomla template where html/php pages are loaded dynamically into a content div via menu items using the following jquery function.

```
$page.load($lnkLoc);
```

The link loads a separate page that reads something like this.

```
    <div class="contentarea">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="page2cont1" title="Page two top" />
</div>
<div class="contentarea">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="page2cont2" title="Page two middle" />
</div>
<div class="contentarea">
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="page2cont3" title="Page two bottom" />
</div>
<footer>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" title="Footer" />
</footer>
```

But, although everything works well, the joomla modules do not display, and instead the following is listed in the html

```
<div class="contentarea"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="page2cont1" title="Page two top"></jdoc:include>
```

The only thing that does load is the footer module because it was present on the initial page load. What am I doing wrong? Am I attempting the impossible?

Comment: What is the extension of the file you're loading? Is it PHP?
Have you tried to use loadposition instead of jdoc statement?
Example: `<div class="contentarea">{loadposition page2cont1}</div>`

Comment: I will try that as soon as I can.

Comment: Loadposition also doesn't work and I have tried countless other ways. The only option is to load modules via PHP I think. When you load new html into the index.php markup it just ignores Jdoc and anything that joomla usually reads.

Comment: Could you please try this PHP code and tell me the result? 
`$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('page2cont1'); foreach( $modules as $module ) echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);`

Comment: I believe I have tried that but will definately let you know how it goes.  I hope it works.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'JModuleHelper' not found in C:\wamp\www\ScriptSauce\templates\scriptsauce\oclistitem2.php on line 3

Comment: This is because your separate file does not "know" about Joomla framework. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your separate page should be a PHP file that requires some Joomla files before rendering the module.
The code below should work:

```
<?php
// Name of this file: loadmodule.php

define( '_JEXEC', 1 ); // This constant is required by all Joomla files.

// The JPATH_BASE should be defined as the path to the root Joomla installation.
define( 'JPATH_BASE', '<path to joomla root directory>' );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

// Those requires below will allow us to use Joomla's instructions.
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS. 'includes' .DS. 'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS. 'includes' .DS. 'framework.php' );

// Instantiate Joomla to be able to use it.
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Loading and rendering the module.
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('testloadmodule');
foreach( $modules as $module ) echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
?>
```

A simple jQuery load instruction like this is able to load the file that renders the module: `$('#module_container').load('loadmodule.php');`